# Multiple editable fields one click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick

I'm trying to create a form that allows the user to edit it similar to the old style of Facebook profile editing. I can't figure out how to change all the elements in a section at the same time.  I can edit one at a time, but not all of them.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="core">
        <div class="profileinfo">

            <div class="gear">
                <label>Primary E-Mail:</label><br />
                <span id="pemail" class="datainfo">myaddress@googlemail.com</span>
                <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
            </div>

            <div class="gear">
                <label>Full Name:</label><br />
                <span id="first" class="datainfo">Johnny</span>
                <span id="middle" class="datainfo">James</span>
                <span id="last" class="datainfo">Appleseed</span>
                <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
            </div>

            <div class="gear">
                <label>Birthday:</label><br />
                <span id="birthday" class="datainfo">August 21, 1989</span>
                <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
            </div>

            <div class="gear">
                <label>Address:</label><br />
                <span id="address1" class="datainfo">123 Test Lane</span><br />
                <span id="address2" class="datainfo">APT 104</span><br />
                <span id="city" class="datainfo">Anywhere</span>
                <span id="state" class="datainfo">FL</span>
                <span id="zip" class="datainfo">55555</span>
                <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
            </div>

            <div class="gear">
                <label>Occupation:</label><br />
                <span id="occupation" class="datainfo">Freelance Web Developer</span>
                <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".editlink").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var dataset = $(this).prev(".datainfo");
    var savebtn = $(this).next(".savebtn");
    var theid   = dataset.attr("id");
    var newid   = theid+"-form";
    var currval = dataset.text();

    dataset.empty();

    $('<input type="text" name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value="'+currval+'" class="hlite">').appendTo(dataset);

    $(this).css("display", "none");
    savebtn.css("display", "block");
});
$(".savebtn").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elink   = $(this).prev(".editlink");
    var dataset = elink.prev(".datainfo");
    var newid   = dataset.attr("id");

    var cinput  = "#"+newid+"-form";
    var einput  = $(cinput);
    var newval  = einput.attr("value");

    $(this).css("display", "none");
    einput.remove();
    dataset.html(newval);

    elink.css("display", "block");
});
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is an image similar to what I want it to look like:

[image: Old Facebook style]

How do I build in the ability to edit each section?  Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhKZU/1/) for you to look at.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with the "old style of Facebook profile editing," can you elaborate on what you are asking? What should happen if I click on one of the "Edit Info" links that isn't happening now?

Comment: I added an image for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the best approach but this will do what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".editlink").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datasets = $(this).prevAll(".datainfo");
    var savebtn = $(this).next(".savebtn");
    datasets.each(function(){
      var theid   = $(this).attr("id");
      var newid   = theid+"-form";
      var currval = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<input type="text" name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value="'+currval+'" class="hlite">');
    });

    $(this).css("display", "none");
    savebtn.css("display", "block");
  });

  $(".savebtn").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elink   = $(this).prev(".editlink");
    var datasets = $(this).prevAll(".datainfo");
    datasets.each(function(){
      var newid   = $(this).attr("id");
      var einput  = $("#"+newid+"-form");
      var newval  = einput.val();
      einput.remove();
      $(this).html(newval);
    });

    $(this).css("display", "none");
    elink.css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Comment: This works if I wanted to edit all the sections at the same time, but I only want to edit one section at a time by creating text areas out of labels.  I highlighted a the area in red.

Comment: Do you want text areas for all the edits or just for address?

Comment: All the edits.  I need to be able to edit the first, middle, and last names, the birthday, the address line 1, address line 2, city, state, and zip.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: ok.. Will it work if you have multiple text boxes instead of a text area for editing first name, middle name and last name? As if we use text area then it would be difficult to identify if there are more than 3 words for this example.

Comment: I'm looking at creating three separate text areas.  I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: You can do it if you want 3 separate textarea or textboxes. Just let me know, I will update my answer. :)

Comment: I do want 3 separate textboxes.  How do I do that?

Comment: Updated the answer. Just try it out :)